# Bootstrap - combination of using box-shadow and overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css

I am using a carousel through `SwiperJS` library which has its own CSS style meaning that you can choose how many slides should be displayed depending on the screen, having equal space between them and equal margins (right and left):

```
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="ss-swiper-slide">
                    <img class="ss-image-slider" src="{% static 'assets/img/theme/light/product-labels.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="ss-swiper-slide">
                    <img class="ss-image-slider" src="{% static 'assets/img/theme/light/product-labels.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="ss-swiper-slide">
                    <img class="ss-image-slider" src="{% static 'assets/img/theme/light/product-labels.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="ss-swiper-slide">
                    <img class="ss-image-slider" src="{% static 'assets/img/theme/light/product-labels.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="ss-swiper-slide">
                    <img class="ss-image-slider" src="{% static 'assets/img/theme/light/product-labels.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="ss-swiper-slide">
                    <img class="ss-image-slider" src="{% static 'assets/img/theme/light/product-labels.png' %}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.swiper-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ss-swiper-slide {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% * 833 / 500);
}

.ss-image-slider {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 39px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px 3px 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 -1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

This works just fine when I use standard images within a slide, having no CSS style applied to them. However, I would like to use `box-shadow` CSS property but due to the `overflow: hidden` property applied to the parent container which is `swiper-container`, for the first and the last slide the shadow is not displayed:

**The container using its standard CSS, without any padding applied which has an equal margin left and right**

[image]

Since this is due to the `overflow: hidden` property, I've tried to add `padding` to the main container but this will affect the carousel, meaning that the margin right will be affected:

**The container with padding and margin-left applied, the box-shadow is visible but the margin right of it is affected**

[image]

```
.swiper-container {
    margin-left: -1.25rem !important;
    padding: 1.25rem !important;
}
```

Is there any way I can solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I *think* I might have a solution, but it isn't bootstrap related so maybe update the question title to remove bootstrap. I am using react and it's the same problem.

Usually with these issues with various slider libraries overflow hidden, you can apply padding and then negative margin to the wrapping elements, but because of the way that swiper calculates the widths and spaceBetween, the space created by the negative margin on the container is then included in the overall width calculation.

I created a solution, but you need to wrap the slider in an additional wrapper, so you remove the overflow hidden on the container, add some padding to the container to equal the padding, and then add the negative margin to wrapper you added.

HTML

```
<!-- additional wrapper for the slider -->
<div class="my-swipe-wrapper">
    <!-- normal swiper slider here -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="my-slide-content">Slide content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* styles to override swiper */

.swiper-container {
    /* change container to overflow visible */
    overflow: visible;
    /* add enough padding to account for the shadow */
    padding: 5px;
}

.my-swipe-wrapper {
    /* add the overflow to the outer wrapper */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* add negative margin to counteract the padding */
    margin: -5px;
}
```

With your particular issue, you have a LOT of shadow, so you will need to add a lot of padding which will make the edges of the outer slides visible (which subjectively might not be too bad).

See my solution on codepen.
https://codepen.io/mcgern/pen/bGpQQmy